# Your query does not include the specified expression. What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: sql, ms-access

When I add currency rate into this code Access tells me that *"Your query does not include the specified expression [Transaction details].[Currency code] = [Currencies].[Currency code] as part of an aggregate function."* What does it mean and how do I fix it?

```
SELECT [Sales structure].Cluster,
       [Sales structure].Country,
       [Transaction details].[Sales company code],
       [Sales structure].[Sales company name],
       Year([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD])      AS [Year],
       Month([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD])     AS [Month],
       Sum([Transaction details].[Sales volume LOC]) AS Sales,
       [Transaction details].[Customer code]
FROM   Currencies
       RIGHT JOIN ([Sales structure]
                   RIGHT JOIN [Transaction details]
                     ON [Sales structure].[Sales company code] = [Transaction details].[Sales company code])
         ON Currencies.[Currency code] = [Transaction details].[Customer code]
GROUP  BY [Sales structure].Cluster,
          [Sales structure].Country,
          [Transaction details].[Sales company code],
          [Sales structure].[Sales company name],
          Year([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]),
          Month([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]),
          [Transaction details].[Customer code],
          Currencies.[CUR/EUR]
HAVING (( [Transaction details].[Currency code] = [Currencies].[Currency code] ))
ORDER  BY Year([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]),
          Month([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]);
```

Comment: By the way, this is the way code turns out when I paste it from Access. Is there any quick way to make the code prettier before I post here?

Comment: Your query does not include the specified expression [Transaction details].[Currency code] = [Currencies].[Currency code] as part of an aggregate function

Comment: I want to add the currency rate into my query from the currencies table. To each row I want to add the currency rate that is matching the currency code of that transaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your having clause.  You already have the condition in the `on` clause for the join, so it is unnecessary in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT [Sales structure].Cluster,
       [Sales structure].Country,
       [Transaction details].[Sales company code],
       [Sales structure].[Sales company name],
       Year([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD])      AS [Year],
       Month([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD])     AS [Month],
       Sum([Transaction details].[Sales volume LOC]) AS Sales,
       [Transaction details].[Customer code]
FROM   Currencies
       RIGHT JOIN ([Sales structure]
                   RIGHT JOIN [Transaction details]
                     ON [Sales structure].[Sales company code] = [Transaction details].[Sales company code])
         ON Currencies.[Currency code] = [Transaction details].[Customer code]
GROUP  BY [Sales structure].Cluster,
          [Sales structure].Country,
          [Transaction details].[Sales company code],
          [Sales structure].[Sales company name],
          Year([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]),
          Month([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]),
          [Transaction details].[Customer code],
          Currencies.[CUR/EUR]
ORDER  BY Year([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]),
          Month([Transaction details].[YYYY-MM-DD]);
```

The specific issue is that the currency codes are not in the `group by` clause and they are not surrounded by aggregation functions in the `having` clause.  In fact, you might want to include the currency in the `select` and `group by` clauses, but that is another issue.